# Android: percentage of PercentRelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-percentrelativelayout

I tried [PercentRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) and I have a question about it.

Positioning to `Button`, `TextView` etc. I am using like that

```
    app:layout_heightPercent="9.595274%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="10.194942%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="6.666664%"
    app:layout_marginRightPercent="6.666664%"
```

Do number of digits after floating point affect the performance badly?

Comment: not really specify but i just want to learn about performance